# Вынос элементов из разметки без дублирования

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

В макете есть блок с таким лейаутом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На определенном брейкпоинте он становится таким:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом это можно сверстать без дублирования фиолетового блока?

Comment: что подразумевается под `опеределенный брейкпоинт`? изменение размера окна, либо выполнение какихто действий...или еще что-то?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц изменение размера лкна

Comment: Читайте про css media-запросы

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц я умею использовать медиа запросы, тут речь идет не об этом, а о том как реализовать это без дублирования.

Comment: ну блоки по цветам...в них же инфа не отличается?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц это абстрактный пример. Каждый цвет это отдельный вид блоков.

Comment: тогда вам нужно  `$(window).on("resize", function(e){})` - это на jQuery. Текущий `Width` можно найти - `e.target.innerWidth`. Ну и просто при определенном размере убирать с одного места блок, и вставлять его в другое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Старые добрые обтекания вам в помощь. Делаете все плитки **float: left** и проставляете конкретные ширины в 50% и 25%. В нужный момент просто меняете эти ширины. Рабочий пример:

https://jsfiddle.net/ufrta3ho/

```
<div class="tiles">
  <div class="tiles__item tiles__item--red"></div>
  <div class="tiles__item tiles__item--yellow"></div>
  <div class="tiles__item tiles__item--blue"></div>
  <div class="tiles__item tiles__item--purple"></div>
</div>


.tiles {

}

  .tiles__item {
    float: left;
  }

  .tiles::after { /* Если не понятно, то погуглить про .clearfix */
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }


  .tiles__item--red {
    width: 50%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
  }

  .tiles__item--yellow {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
  }

  .tiles__item--blue {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .tiles__item--purple {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: purple;
  }


@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .tiles__item--blue {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .tiles__item--purple {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Я б сделал как то так

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        section {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col m-2" style="background-color: red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum delectus, quidem nulla quis distinctio asperiores eos esse quasi reprehenderit iusto, tempore architecto eligendi et quibusdam facilis provident, blanditiis perspiciatis consectetur.
            Suscipit tempore facilis inventore ratione maxime error ipsum expedita explicabo accusantium eaque. Consequuntur magni facilis laboriosam debitis expedita dolorem ut est aut? Dolorem nesciunt temporibus possimus quis eligendi, at voluptatum.
            Quaerat labore reiciendis quo pariatur suscipit ipsum impedit aspernatur excepturi sed, ad ex, iste ipsam architecto repellat autem qui. Praesentium et maxime laudantium nemo voluptas adipisci quia qui, necessitatibus exercitationem.
            Reiciendis magnam, sunt necessitatibus expedita numquam commodi magni ipsam? Tempora quidem sapiente fuga ea, magnam cupiditate eligendi facere fugit esse officia, magni ab nemo odio excepturi provident at? Reiciendis, harum.
            Sequi deserunt aliquid quas laborum ad error, odit repellat, quaerat ratione consectetur corporis culpa! Atque magnam, velit natus quaerat hic aliquam deleniti voluptatem temporibus voluptate reiciendis numquam, ad, dignissimos in!</div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="row mt-2" style="background-color: green">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi natus et animi, illo praesentium quod, alias blanditiis quibusdam dicta accusamus esse. Ducimus quo suscipit cum, ut excepturi amet harum optio.Hic, mollitia sit amet, minima quaerat ducimus sunt earum, quos veniam incidunt doloremque culpa nemo qui vitae neque cumque? Quidem, voluptas distinctio repudiandae eius incidunt nisi maiores numquam. Sit, illo?
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="old">
                    <div class="col-lg col-md-12 m-2" style="background-color: blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut, pariatur?</div>
                    <div id="column" class="col-lg m-2" style="background-color: purple">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cupiditate tempora voluptatem dolor fugiat sapiente architecto.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="min" style="background-color: purple">
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
            $(window).on("resize", function(e){
                let col = $("#column");
                if (e.target.innerWidth < 992){
                    $("#column").remove();
                    $("#min").empty().append(col.clone());
                }
                else {
                    $("#min").empty();
                    if ($("#old #column").length === 0) $("#old").append(col.clone())
                }
            });
        });
        
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Такой вариант хуже обычного дублирования тем что у пользователя может быть выключен js и ничего не будет работать. Ну и использовать jq тоже такое себе.